# Sum of different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using an ERP that has a semi-"graphical" SQL-based report writer.

The way our software works is that products can be "Masters" or "Members" (or neither, but lets ignore that for now). Essentially a product can be the "parent" of a group or a "child" of another products group. So say you have the following table:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       Product       |   ProductMaster  |     Quantity     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          A          |                  |        200       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          A1         |         A        |        50        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          A2         |         A        |        50        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          A3         |         A        |        25        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Product A is the Master, the others are members of A.

What I would like to do is have one row per product that combines the quantities of Masters and all their Members (in this case, one row with `Quantity = 325`), and I can't figure out how to do it. I can get the Sum of all the members, by putting Group By ProductMaster, but then I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is only one level of depth, you can use `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(ProductMaster, Product) as ProductMaster, sum(Quantity)
from t
group by coalesce(ProductMaster, Product);
```

Note:  This assumes that *blank* means `NULL`.  If it means something else, then you'll want a `CASE` instead of `COALESCE()`.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. By one level of depth, you mean that a Master has one set of members, and members can't be masters themselves? Because yes, I believe that is the case. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: And that works. Now I have to figure out what exactly Coalesce does. Thanks!